# Can I make auto sum in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want sum single row in last column in same row like

```
-------------------------------
Value 1    Value 2     Sum
-------------------------------
  2           5         ? 
  5          10         ? 
-------------------------------
```

I want to sum this values automatically

I tried to add (Sum(Value1 + Value2)) in default value for Sum

Comment: Your question is not clear do explain more. Also post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I added what I tried

Comment: What type are `Value 1 `and `Value 2` and why there is `2.` value instead of `2` or `2.00`

Comment: You can't use SUM() like that. It is used to sum values in one column across a lot of rows. You can SUM columns in each row like I show here: https://colinmackay.scot/2017/07/11/aggregate-of-columns-not-rows/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Value 1] [INT] NULL,
    [Value 2] [INT] NULL,
    [Value 3]  AS ([Value 1] + [Value 2])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test ([Value 1], [Value 2])
VALUES (1, 2)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Test
```

Results:

```
Value 1   Value 2   Value 3
   1          2         3
```

Comment: `[Value 1]+[Value 1]` doesn't make any sense

Comment: oh i am sorry i need to upgrade this one

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this if you all ready have table drop the column of that total then:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [ColumnName] AS ([Column1] * [Column2])
```

use * or + or - as you want

If you will create new table, the code will be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName] (Col1 int, Col2 int , Col3 as ([col1] * [col2])) ;
```

use * or + or - as you want